# Использование и переопределение переменной в методе forEach класса Stream

Tags: java, java-stream

Как можно sql зариплейсить в стриме форич? Мне подчеркивает "variable used in lambda should be final"

```
Strong sql = "select * from #table#"; 
listMacros.forEach(macros ->
    {
        if(macros.contains(entity.getMacros()) && !"".equals(entity.getEntityIdValue())) {
            sql = sql.replace(macros, entity.getEntityIdValue());
            return;
         } else if(macros.contains(entity.getMacros()) && "".equals(entity.getEntityIdValue())) {
            sql = sql.replace(macros, entity.getEntityName());
            return;
         }
     })
```

Answer (score 1):

Через метод `forEach` нельзя, поскольку переменные, используемые в лямбда-выражении, не должны изменяться. Чтобы решить эту проблему, просто не используйте лямбда-выражение. Вместо этого вы можете использовать цикл `foreach`:

```
    for (Macros macros : listMacros) {
        // your code here
    }
```

Однако следует знать, что в этом случае вы не можете изменить объекты итерируемой коллекции. Если же вам нужно их изменить, вы можете использовать итератор:

```
    for (Iterator<Macros> iterator; iterator.hasNext(); ) {
        Macros macros = iterator.next();
        // your code here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, можно использовать [Stream::reduce](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-). Примерный код:

```
String sql = "select * from #table#";
String processedSql = macrosList.stream().reduce(sql, (s, m) -> processMacro(s, m, entity));
```

где

```
static String processMacro(String sql, String macro, Entity entity) {
  if (macro.contains(entity.getMacros())) {
    if (!"".contentEquals(entity.getEntityIdValue())) {
      return sql.replace(macro, entity.getEntityIdValue());
    } else if ("".contentEquals(entity.getEntityIdValue())) {
      return sql.replace(macro, entity.getEntityName());
    }
  }
  return sql;
}
```

Если у вас не будут при замене появляться новые макросы, должно работать. В общем случае нужно понимать, какие требования накладываются на функцию, используемую в `reduce`.